# Area of a triangle with sides $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$,$\sqrt{y^2+z^2}$,$\sqrt{z^2+x^2}$

Tags: analytic-geometry, area

Sides of a triangle ABC are $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$,$\sqrt{y^2+z^2}$ and $\sqrt{z^2+x^2}$ where x,y,z are non-zero real numbers,then area of triangle ABC is

(A)$\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{x^2y^2+y^2z^2+z^2x^2}$

(B)$\frac{1}{2}(x^2+y^2+z^2)$

(C)$\frac{1}{2}(xy+yz+zx)$

(D)$\frac{1}{2}(x+y+z)\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}$

I tried applying Heron's formula but calculations are very messy and simplification is difficult.I could not think of any other method to find this area.Can someone assist me in solving this problem.

Comment: in case you have the answers, all you have to do, is to check some triangles. just let $x=y=z=1$ , than you get Equilateral triangle with $a=\sqrt{2}$. than , if I see correctly , only one answer is valid. because the are of such triangle is $\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$

Comment: HINT:

$$A(x,0,0);B(0,y,0),C(0,0,z)$$

See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/128991/how-to-calculate-area-of-3d-triangle

Comment: @Brahmagupta . Hope Brahmagupta got fully clarified  about Barahmagupta's formula.

Comment: @Narasimham,yes Sir,i did.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**hint**: Let $a = \sqrt{x^2+y^2}, b = \sqrt{y^2+z^2}, c = \sqrt{z^2+x^2} \to a^2 = x^2+y^2, b^2 = y^2+z^2, c^2= z^2+x^2 $. Use this and Cosine Law to find $\cos^2 A$, then $\sin^2 A$, and use $S^2 = \dfrac{b^2c^2\sin^2 A}{4}$, to find $S^2$ and then take square-root to get back $S$.

Answer (score 5):

There is such a triangle $\triangle\subset{\mathbb R}^3$ with vertices
$${\bf 0}=(0,0,0), \quad{\bf a}:=(x,y,0), \quad {\bf b}:=(0,y,z)\ .$$
Its area is given by
$${\rm area\,}(\triangle)={1\over2}\bigl|{\bf a}\times{\bf b}\bigr|={1\over2}\sqrt{y^2z^2+z^2x^2+x^2y^2}\ .$$

Answer (score 2):

Use cosine rule to find say $\angle C$ then use formula of area as follows

Area of $\triangle ABC$ $$=\frac{1}{2}(a)(b)\sin C=\frac{1}{2}(a)(b)\sqrt{1-(\cos C)^2}$$ $$=\frac{1}{2}(\sqrt{x^2+y^2})(\sqrt{y^2+z^2})\sqrt{1-\left(\frac{(\sqrt{x^2+y^2})^2+\sqrt{y^2+z^2})^2-(\sqrt{x^2+z^2})^2}{2\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\sqrt{y^2+z^2}}\right)^2}$$
$$=\frac{1}{2}(\sqrt{x^2+y^2})(\sqrt{y^2+z^2})\sqrt{\frac{4(x^2+y^2)(y^2+z^2)-(x^2+y^2+y^2+z^2-x^2-z^2)^2}{4(x^2+y^2)(y^2+z^2)}}$$

$$=\frac{1}{2}\frac{(\sqrt{x^2+y^2})(\sqrt{y^2+z^2})}{2(\sqrt{x^2+y^2})(\sqrt{y^2+z^2})}\sqrt{4x^2y^2+4y^4+4z^2x^2+4y^2z^2-(2y^2)^2}$$
 $$=\frac{1}{4}\sqrt{4(x^2y^2+y^2z^2+z^2x^2)}$$ $$=\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{x^2y^2+y^2z^2+z^2x^2}$$
Option (A) is correct

Answer (score 2):

For such form of the side lengths, the most convenient 
would be a variation of the 
[Heron's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heron%27s_formula)
for the area:

\begin{align}
S&=\tfrac14\sqrt{4a^2b^2-(a^2+b^2-c^2)^2}
\\
S&=\tfrac14\sqrt{
4(x^2+y^2)(y^2+z^2)-
(x^2+y^2+y^2+z^2-z^2-x^2)^2
}
\\
&=\tfrac14\sqrt{4(x^2+y^2)(y^2+z^2)-4y^4}
\\
&=\tfrac12\sqrt{x^2 y^2+y^2 z^2+z^2 x^2}.
\end{align}