# Calculate the surface and altitude of a triangle determined with three points

Tags: vectors

The triangle is determined with three points: $A(1, -2, 8), B(0, 0, 4), C(6, 2, 0)$. How do I calculate its surface and altitude from B?

Comment: What did you try? What are your thoughts? Do you know about the scalar product?

Comment: popular question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/128991/how-to-calculate-area-of-3d-triangle

Comment: Once you have the area using any of the methods in the linked question above, divide by $AC$ to get the altitude.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT**

We can proceed as follow

- consider the line $l_{AC}$ and a generic point $P\in l_{AC}$
- consider the line $l_{BP}$ and find $\bar P$ such that $l_{B\bar P}\perp l_{AC}$ by the condition

$$v_{B\bar P}\cdot v_{AC}=0$$

- then the height is $B\bar P$ and the area is $S=\frac12 AC\cdot B\bar P$

As an alternative

- find the lenght $AB$, $BC$, $AC$ and the area by [**Heron's formula**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heron%27s_formula)
- from $S=\frac12 AC \cdot H_B$ find $H_B$