# How do I go about calculating the perimeter of a triangle that consists of three vertices of a cube?

Tags: triangles

I'm given a unit cube. The task is to find the perimeter of triangle ACE. I have no other information, but considering it's a unit cube that should be more than enough.

Am I looking for an answer like [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/128995/873402) by any chance?

Anyways, cheers!

Comment: That would be unnecessary. You just need to apply Pythagoreas' Theorem multiple times.

Comment: What are $A, C$ and $E$?

Comment: In this [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle#Using_coordinates) there is a formula for the area of a general triangle in ${\mathbb R}^3$ given the verctices' $3$-dimensional coordinates.

Comment: @user2661923 Thanks. Apparently I misread the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question would have been more specific if the annotation of the vertices were given.
So, the edges of the triangle can either be 1. a **surface diagonal** i.e., the diagonal connecting the running along the surface of the cube, 2. a **body diagonal** i.e.,  the diagonal connecting the vertices at opposite ends of the cube 3. an **edge**.
**Egde** = a =  1 
**surface diagonal** = s = $\sqrt{a^2 + a^2}$ = $\sqrt{1^1 + 1^1}$ = $\sqrt{2}$ 
**body diagonal** =$ \sqrt{a^2 + s^2} = \sqrt{1^2 + 2} = \sqrt{3}$

see which of these three are the edges of your triangle and add them.

Comment: +1 : Adroit picking up of the slack of the query's ambiguity.